# What is fixed point of the exponential function $e^{ax}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fixed-points

Given $$f(x)=e^{ax}$$
where $0<a\ll e^{-1}$ and $x>0$

What are the fixed points of this function? Obviously, there are two points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ satisfy the $f(x)=x$. One of them is close to 1 and Another one is far from 1. 
Is there any analytical solution to this or any approximation of the solution?
Thanks!

Comment: In terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), the fixed point is equal to 
$$
x = -\frac{W(-a)}{a}
$$
we can get both answers using the two branches of the Lambert W function, $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.

Comment: To derive this solution note that
$$
x = e^{ax} \iff (-ax) = -ae^{ax} \iff (-ax)e^{(-ax)} = -a
$$

Comment: That comment should specify the two *real* branches of the Lambert W function over $\Bbb R$

Comment: $\text{Om}(\text{nom})^3,$ you should promote to an answer.

Comment: @AdrianKeister fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), the fixed points are equal to 
$$
x = -\frac{W_k(-a)}{a}
$$
where $W_k$ is the $k$th branch of the Lambert W function.  The two real solutions that occur when $0 < a < e^{-1}$ come from the $k = 0$ and $k = -1$ branches.

To verify that the $x$ of the above form solve $x = e^{ax}$, it suffices to note that
$$
x = e^{ax} \iff (-ax) = -ae^{ax} \iff (-ax)e^{(-ax)} = -a.
$$

Comment: Does this work for the Complex Exponential? I mean, we fix a branch logz of thelog , so that  $$ e^z =z \rightarrow z=logz \rightarrow e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(cosy + isiny)=logz = ln|z|+ iargz $$ But I dont see this leading anywhere useful: $$e^x siny=ln|z| ; e^x cosy =argz $$

Comment: @MSIS As the Wikipedia article says, the Lambert W function is also defined for complex inputs.